# How can i use the aws cmds in Powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am trying to run the following:

```
      aws s3api put-object --bucket   .....
```

But i get an error:

```
       aws : The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function
```

Do i need to install any module , how can i get this to work ?

Comment: Please search this site for the phrase **is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function**. This question has been asked and answered here literally dozens (if not hundreds) of times before. Certainly, at least one of those existing answers will help you figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: You read the answers to every one of those previous questions and found nothing to help? I have my doubts about both of those things. My search to isolate it only to questions and answers related to powershell with the search phrase **[powershell] is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function** returns just under 2,000 results. (Enclosing the tag information in square brackets means that the results are filtered to questions and answers having that tag.)

Comment: Yes it does , i have tried the following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html#getting-started-install-instructions       and then 
Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore
Import-Module AWSPowerShell.NetCore    , but still doesnt recognize

Comment: Then you've not found the answer that actually solves the problem yet. Keep reading.

Comment: yes i read the whole page , doesnt provide a solution .. as it dos not work, am i missing something ?     aws s3api ... should then work in powershell , but it does not

Comment: Two thousand posts take more than one page. What part of **do more reading - we don't need another duplicate of the same question** isn't clear?

Comment: I realize that ,  but all im asking is that if someone has come across this error can they provide some insight .. nothing more

Comment: Its ok , i have managed to work it out myself !

Comment: @Sally: The linked post aims to provide a comprehensive troubleshooting guide for problems such as yours. If the solution you found yourself is _not_ covered in the linked post, let us know.

Comment: I have found and solved the issue